# Creating new variable in SQL with case statements

Tags: sql

Beginners SQL question: How do I insert a new categorical variable into a table?

After running the following code in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
create table test (
  memberid varchar(10),
  sex char(1),
  healthcost float(10)
  );

insert into test (memberid, sex, healthcost)
values ('A0003','M',25000);
insert into test (memberid, sex, healthcost)
values ('A0002','F',55000);
insert into test (memberid, sex, healthcost)
values ('A0001','M',10000);

alter table test
add healthcost_catg varchar(20);

insert into test (healthcost_catg)
select case when healthcost > 20000 then '> $20,000' as healthcost_catg
       else '<= $20,000' as healthcost_catg
end  
from test
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error at Command Line : 18 Column : 54
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column alias should be after the case.

```
insert into test (healthcost_catg)
select case when healthcost > 20000 then '> $20,000'
       else '<= $20,000' end as healthcost_catg
from test
```

Also, I think you want an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`.

```
update t set
healthcost_catg =  case when healthcost > 20000 then '> $20,000' else '<= $20,000'end  
from test t
```

Comment: I see "end" keyword above "from test" ??

Comment: "Also, I think you want an UPDATE, not an INSERT" I can't believe I've missed that! +1

Comment: The INSERT code almost works - it adds three new lines with null values for memberid, sex, and healthcost and the correct values for healthcost_catg in the 4th column. The UPDATE statement gives me an error message: "SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: Found the problem - removed the `from test t` line in the UPDATE statement and it worked great.